# Adjust the srt timestamp subtitles in a batch way

Tags: video, subtitle

I have such a srt subtitle file

```
1
00:00:03,575 --> 00:00:05,134
Paul's letter to the Romans

2
00:00:05,134 --> 00:00:07,164
it's one of the longest and most significant things

3
00:00:07,165 --> 00:00:10,714
ever written by the man who was formerly known as Saul of Tarsus.

4
00:00:11,262 --> 00:00:14,551
He was a Jewish rabbi belonging to a group known as the Pharisees
```

It delayed 2 seconds to the video playing, 
How could I minus the 2 seconds to all the timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

You can use my software, [Subtitld](https://subtitld.jonata.org), to do that. You can get it for free on [Snap store](https://snapcraft.io/subtitld). Use the Gap add/remove tool to make that adjustment:

https://youtu.be/AzlAJXCwXHI